# tools for visualising money flows in a complex company structure

Tags: visualization, blockchain, finance

I'm working on a project where we want to visualise money flows in complex company structures. The context is real-estate investment in Berlin, Germany, which faces currently an acute shortage in apartments.

Berlin is a highly attractive market for investors, as the market is still very affordable compared to other European capitals. But as authorities do not support building affordable housing, and don't build themselves, private investors have a relative dominance.

Among private investors, a big part use company networks spread across Europe to aggressively avoid taxes. They use every legal possibility, with mother companies European tax havens like Jersey, Luxemburg and Cyprus. The finance minister of Berlin estimates losses due to tax avoidance by RE investors to 100 to 200 Mio € yearly.

Our project aims to show how these investors work. The goal is to make this highly technical subject understandable for non-specialists, first step to raise public awareness.

We want to show in detail how money flows across company structures that can have 30+ subsidiaires spread across Europe. Here are examples: https://ibb.co/album/kPT6Jv

[Example of a complex company structure: the investor Taliesin, Berlin/Jersey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayZn5.jpg)

You can see that as an organigram, these structures are more like a puzzle and need a specialist to explain what they mean.

The representation should be dynamic, so that you can see the rents rising from the houses, trickling through the network, ending at the beneficiairies. Ideally, you'd see how much money remains at each station of the network.

A user, or a tenant, could enter the amount of his rent in a field, say 1000 €, and then follow its path through the companies. At the end he'd see that of his rent, 140 € remain in the house for upkeeping, 220 € are used for management costs of the owners, 240 € go to the shell companies and the managers companies, 380 € go the banks as interest rates on the company's loans, 20 € are paid in taxes.

This example is taken from the analysis of the investor Taliesin in Berlin, one of the most agressive tax avoiders, and are actual figures. I co-wrote an article on Taliesin for the Berlin daily Tagesspiegel, 8 oct 2016: https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/share-deals-auf-dem-berliner-immobilienmarkt-wie-investoren-den-kreuzberger-buechertisch-ausbooteten/14658204.html

In our project, "Who do I actually pay rent to", we'll instruct tenants how to research and transmit the data to an analyst-team, who'll then verify and reconstruct the money flow.

Hope this question is not too long.

So back to the actual question:

- is there a tool to visualise this type of flows? I've found a couple of blockchain/bitcoin visualisation and ready-mades, like Key lines
- do you know developers who could help in finding and adapting the visualisation tools? There will be a couple of other visualisations to do.

The project will be funded and there will be a large chunk of the money reserved to the visualisation tool, as this is main aspect.

Any questions, please ask.

Looking forward for your answers.

Best,
Adrian

Comment: This question is not relevant for Stack Overflow, see [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the Help Center

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for that, I have not seen this question asked before though. Please show me if I'm mistaken, thanks.

Comment: You don't understand me, this question should be closed because it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a tool to visualise this type of flows? I've found a couple
>   of blockchain/bitcoin visualisation and ready-mades, like Key lines.

You need a data visualisation app.
In short Yes, this can be built with Python and the use of d3.js to display the data in the way you want.

Python : https://www.python.org/
D3.JS : https://d3js.org/

> do you know developers who could help in finding and adapting the
>   visualisation tools? There will be a couple of other visualisations to
>   do

Yes, me.

Comment: The question is related not to the technical visualization (you can use any platform for this, Excel, C#, Java, Python, JavaScript, etc.), but the financial specific solution.

Comment: The Question is : is there a tool to visualise this type of flows? I've found a couple of blockchain/bitcoin visualisation and ready-mades, like Key lines

do you know developers who could help in finding and adapting the visualisation tools? There will be a couple of other visualisations to do.

Comment: What do your processes have to do with blockchain and bitcoin?

Comment: I suggest to close this question. It is too broad. To visualize any processes there are hundreads of frameworks/libraries in VB, Excel, C++, C#, Java, Python, JavaScribpt, etc.

Comment: @mentallurg Bitcoin are transactions from one party to another. There are tools to visualise that. Corporations that consists of several interlinked companies are networks of separate entities, or parties, that have transactions between them. The nature of this transactions will determine if they taxes, and if so, how much.

So basically it's the same thing, just one is bitcoin, the other is corporate accounting.

The question is not really broad: it's actually quite specific, since it is based on existing EU accounting rules & tax laws

Comment: @camem_bert: How many of these companies do really use bitcoin? I'd guess NONE. So why are you talking about bitcoin? Dear moderators, please close this thread as too broad and not relevant for software development.

Comment: @mentallurg I think you can use any flow of money with a tool made for that, regardless of the currency the transfer is being made.

Or do you think a booking software can only be used say for yoga appointments? Not for fitness oder doctors? Ok you might be right...

They should develop a word processor for journalism, for diaries, for academic texts, for song lyrics. Makes sense...